# How to get a correct duration in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I have two effort driven tasks with a work of 8h for each of them. If I delete the duration of task 5, Project fills the field with `1 day?`

[image]

What I need to do is update the work for this task, for example I update to 9 hrs then modifies it back to 8 hrs

[image]

In this case it automatically updates the Duration as expected because John Doe works on this task at 20%.

The problem is that if I delete the duration (mistake), it goes back to `1 day?`.

How can I be sure my Durations are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you want to change the default duration:

In Project 2010, the default task duration unit is days, but you can change it to be minutes, hours, weeks, or months:

Click the File tab, and then click Options.

In the Project Options dialog box, click Schedule.

Under Scheduling options in this project, in the Duration is entered in list, select a duration unit.

To use the same setting automatically in all future projects, select All New Projects in the Scheduling options in this project list.

Comment: It is not what I look for. I would like the duration to be automatically adjusted to the work and the resources

Comment: but there are scheduling limitation defaults, for instance an 8 hour day. youll need to change these things so they dont autocorrect.